# Playout software in linux

Tags: video-streaming, dvb

Is there any software in linux doing stream generation for digital-video processing equipment
like streamXpress in windows?

Answer (score 1):

There are some, but very basic and not quite what a normal TV channel would do. You should read [this](http://blog.eltrovemo.com/364/diy-broadcast-how-to-build-your-own-tv-channel-with-open-source-other-goodies/) article. It mentions [OpenPlayout](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openplayout/) and [MLT](http://www.mltframework.org) as playout systems for Linux, but personally I would look towards Windows application [CasparCG](http://casparcg.com), as it's more flexible and mature (and 12 channels of Swedish television use it).